# Appending the table using jquery multiple times

Tags: jquery, html

This are my jquery functions

```
var status; 
$('.status').click(function(e) {
     status= $(this).attr('id');                    
     //$('#test').html('<p>Scrolled: '+ status +'</p>');                
     callAjax();
     display();
});
```

This function above gets id of the hyper reference clicked and stores it in a variable.
and call other function.

```
 var id = [];
 var values = [];
 function callAjax(){            
     id = [];
     values = [];
     $("#"+ status +"> td").each(function(index){                
     id.push($(this).attr("id"))
     values.push($(this).text());
     //alert($(this).attr("id")+" "+$(this).text());                          
  });           
}
```

This function above retrives all the values from row and stores it in a array.Using this array values i will create a new table and display it below the hyperlink that was clicked (whose div is stored status variable)

```
  function display(){               
            $("#"+status).append('<table id="newtable" border="1"> <tr> <td>'+values[0]+'</td><td>'+values[1]+'</td></tr></table>');
  }
```

in display() function when i am first time appending the table its working fine, but when again link is clicked it appends one more table.

output

[image]

here when i click on link first time it displays the table correctly, but when i click the same link its appending the same table and second problem is when i click on other link first table should get disappeared.

help...

Comment: Do you want the next click replace the old table, or do you want the results to be added to the existing table?

Comment: This is exactly what your code says it does...append a table every time the function display gets called. Try removing any previous ones before the append.

Comment: i will upload an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
function display(){ 
       $("#newtable").remove();   //removes table tag        
    $("#"+status).append('<table id="newtable" border="1"> <tr> <td>'+values[0]+'</td>                             <td>'+values[1]+'</td></tr></table>');
    }
```

Comment: even empty replace the tag to which i want to append

Comment: @Azuu empty will remove all the tags inside the `$("#"+status)` For [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: that is what i dont want, inside this i have a <a href> which should not get empty

Comment: @Azuu try `$("#newtable").remove()`

Answer (score 1):

Clear the `$("#"+status)` before appending .

```
 function display(){       
 $("#"+status).clear();      
 $("#"+status).append('<table id="newtable" border="1">
               <tr> <td>'+values[0]+'</td><td>'+values[1]+'</td></tr></table>');
        }
```

or as @juhana mentioned in comment

```
  function display(){       
     $("#"+status).html('<table id="newtable" border="1">
               <tr> <td>'+values[0]+'</td><td>'+values[1]+'</td></tr></table>');
            }
```

Comment: I suppose this works, but it would be much easier to just change `.append()` to `.html()`.

Comment: clear() is not working.. its not displaying the table even once        and when i use .empty() it replaces the id to which i want to append.

Answer (score 0):

first you clear the div  and append the div.append mean just append the wat you giving ex:in div contains the text1 means if you append the test2 mean it ll append the test 1 test2 like wise u jsust clear the div and append the value

```
 function display(){   
                $("#"+status).empty();          
                $("#"+status).append('<table id="newtable" border="1"> <tr> <td>'+values[0]+'</td><td>'+values[1]+'</td></tr></table>');
            }
```